# OpenCV 3.2 - Can't create VideoCapure from IP

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to catch video stream from IP camera in OpenCV, but OpenCV can't create `VideoCapture` from url, but I've got EmguCV project, where I can capture video using this url. Code:

```
const std::string  url = "rtsp://admin:12345@192.168.6.206:554/RVi/1/1";
VideoCapture cap(url); 
if (!cap.isOpened())  
    return -1;

namedWindow("frame", 1);
while (true)

{
    Mat frame;

    cap >> frame; 
    imshow("frame", frame);

    if (waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
}
return 0;
```

Just for test I install OpenCV 2.9.11, and even theve everything is works.
What I do wrong?

Comment: is it  H264 encoded stream ?

Comment: Can you access this stream via vlc?

Comment: it's H264, and i can access it with vlc. I even can access it with EmguCV

Answer (score 0):

what you need is to provide a file extension, instead of a URL. You can add the same to your URL as:

`std::string  url = "rtsp://admin:12345@192.168.6.206:554/RVi/1/1/x.mjpeg";`

Comment: Ok, I've tried to add some file extensions and it still don't work. Anyway, I got another camera, and I can access it with VLS and EmguCV project by adress: [link](rtsp://192.168.6.235/user=admin_password=xxx_channel=1_stream=0.sdp)  but OpenCV still can't see it. It got a file extension, so I guess problem is not here